# Creating new Rails project with Aptana fails with "/<project name>/public does not exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, aptana, radrails

I am using Windows 7 and Ruby 1.8.7.  I get the following error message when I start a new Rails project:

**Problem Occured**

'Replace project index file' has encountered a problem.  Resource '/Foobar/public' does not exist.  (where 'Foobar' is the name of my new project).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found a workaround: Create the project but UNCHECK the part about generating a rails skeleton.  Then open a console, navigate to the project's parent directory, and run `rails <project name>`.  The skeleton will generate in the folder, and then you can refresh the project directory within Aptana/Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

When new project is created using radrails, RadRails execute the command **rails beta -d sqlite3** which is older syntax and the new syntax is **rails new beta -d sqlite3** So unless the Aptana Teams invokes new rails functionality the workaround would be to use the methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the same procedure as mentioned above....
But for me Rails  didn't work.

> rails new "project name" worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because my project had spaces in the name. Removed the spaces and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem but in web projects and using a network directory. I create the project in local and then move it to network unity.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your IDE as an administrator. Right click your IDE icon -> "Run as administrator".
Now your IDE will have the appropriate privileges to write files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the interpreter that the IDE uses worked for me. Go to `windows->preferences->ruby->installed interpreters` then select the one that comes with your installation of Aptana Studio, mine's name is `org.jruby_1.2.0.9`... It worked like a charm for me. I hope that helped.